# How to put constant in the first position when using statsmodel?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am trying to run a regression by using statsmodels of python. But the problem is that because I used fillna(1) to fill the dataframe, so there are some regressor as a constant.

When I use

```
sm.OLS(y,x).fit().params
```

The order of these parameters is wrong, like this

```
    coeff
x1  0.7017
x2  0.0143
x3  -1.0361
x4  -0.0033
x5  0.7583
x6  -0.0081
x7  -0.4451
x8  -0.0024
const   0.0153
x9  0.0153
x10 0.0153
x11 0.0153
x12 0.0153
x13 0.0153
x14 0.0153
x15 0.0153
x16 0.0153
x17 0.0153
```

Because from x9 to x17 are constants.
Could anyone solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this question by using

```
x=sm.add_constant(x, has_constant='add')
```

Using has_constant='add', make sure the statsmodels add a constant and avoid the situation above.